# Part equivalent to \@chapapp{}

Tags: sectioning

I was recently poking around a cls file with a custom chapter formatting.

It uses `\@chapapp{}` and I would like to find out if there is a part equivalent other than `\partname`?

Comment: No, or at least no in the standard classes. The name for parts is constant.

Comment: `\partname` is what you're looking for. The existence of `\@chapapp` is due to the fact that `\chaptername` is used in the normal text, but `\appendixname` is used in the appendix.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The macro `\@chapapp` is initially defined to expand to `\chaptername`, but `\appendix` redefines it to be `\appendixname`.

The standard classes define `\partname` and the language definition files of `babel` should have a definition for it. Since there's no change in `\partname` during the document, no other command is provided.